# Getting hardware issue Related to android Voice Button after Android update

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, hardware, volume

So this is a new type of issue I am currently facing, Recently I ran an **APK** of **React Native** Application I recently built on my system. After running that **APK** successfully. I started facing some issues regarding my phone's ** *sound key* **.

I tried restarting the device [**Samsung**], So it stopped showing the **1st issue**. But after a few days a **2nd issue** arrives.

**1st issue** => The volume up button stops working manually and starts increasing the volume automatically.

**2n issue** => Now whenever I write a new **Text Message** to someone it automatically starts increasing the font size of the text.

I gave a reboot to the device and even formated it, but nothing helped.
I want to know if it's a software side issue or hardware? So that before submitting the device to a **Samsung** store, If it's a software issue and if I can fix it. It will save me some bucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this issue and that was due to the Hardware issue that has happened to my Android Samsung device and I researched it.

This type of issue was very common with users having that old version of smartphones and that is why new design keys for power and volume were introduced in most of the new smartphones which were launched in later 2016. This has actually reduced the key issues and if in case there is an issue, now it is easier to fix it since the keys are separated from the board as it was used to be earlier.

Also, some useful sources if someone is facing a similar issue in their old version android devices.

[Volume Slider](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/get-android-9-0-pies-volume-slider-any-phone-control-media-volume-by-default-0183845/).

[Volume button not working](https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-android-volume-buttons/)